# Is there any way to find out if a HTTP Get Request is coming from a hyperlink or by directly entering the address in the address bar?

Tags: spring, web-services, httprequest

Im using Spring MVC: Spring security. 
There is one GET request which downloads a form. I want to know whether the request was made using an hyperlink or from the address bar.

Is there any attribute in the HttpRequest object that can differentiate between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `Referer` header to see if the request is coming from a link in another page. See explanations on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) and the entry in the [HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.36). Directly entering the URL in the address bar will not have the header in the request.

Since you ask your question in a security context do note that **you cannot count on this check** because any request can be faked (i.e. I could use a basic command line app to make your application think I'm requesting from a browser). Also, there are plugins that deactivate this feature in browsers for privacy considerations.